# Diesel generator with ethernet connection

Tags: networking, ethernet, remote-control

I wonder if there is any diesel generator that has Ethernet (or any network) connection so that it can be monitored and turned on and off remotely? Or is there any system that can provide such functionality?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: https://dcautogen.com/product/v3-autogen-generator-controller-with-wifi/

Comment: https://www.generac.com/all-products/parts-accessories/mobile-link-wifi

Comment: yes they exist, google *generator control wifi*

Comment: *kohler generator wifi*

Comment: https://www.midwestgenerators.com/can-my-generator-be-connected-to-the-internet-kohler-oncue-plus/